# Are there famous Storm Sorcerers (or similar) in the Forgotten Realms lore?

Tags: dnd-5e, lore, sorcerer

I'm writing a [D&D companion book for Hoard of the Dragon Queen](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/437637/) (1489 DR), and in the final chapter, an unexpected ally would help the party. This ally uses the power of thunder and lightning to storm (*heh, see what I did there*) the flying fortress of Skyreach Castle.

Originally, this ally was just a previous character (a Storm Sorcerer) from my table. However, to publish the book, I'd like a more recognizable name. I tried to google for famous storm sorcerers, but didn't have much luck.

**Are there famous and powerful storm sorcerer characters or characters from Forgotten Realms lore that could fit the description of a strong combatant that relies on the powers of storms to fight, and who could bring a fight to a flying fortress of Cloud Giants?**

In the limit, I might use some name like Mordenkainen, even if it's not a perfect fit.

PS: if you find a character that fits the description, but shouldn't be alive this year, worry not! We can make an apprentice of that character, or a descendant, or something else. As long as it's a recognizable name that readers can look-up for more information, then it's what I need.

Comment: In which year does the adventure take place?

Comment: To be clear, are you doing this under license from Hasbro/WotC? Fairly sure you *can't* use much from outside the 5E SRD, especially stuff like famous names from copyrighted material (the SRD explicitly excludes them, by publishing spells with famous names without the famous name attached, e.g. *Tiny Hut* instead of *Leomund's Tiny Hut*), without that legal arrangement (assuming you intend to profit from it at least, which is often what it means to "publish"; if it's just free-to-all fan-made material, things are a bit more wibbly).

Comment: @ShadowRanger "free-to-all fan-made material" is literally a description of one of the licenses that WorC offers for people to use. It's hardly wibbly at all; tge terms of the license are clearly spelled out.

Comment: @nick012000: Cool. I remember them looking at changes to their licensing structure, but not being a content publisher of any stripe, I wasn't paying close attention to how it all turned out. So yeah, if it's not-for-profit, you follow the rules for that license, if it's for profit, you're either sticking to the SRD (no famous names except a handful introduced by accident IIRC) or making individual legal arrangements.

Comment: @ShadowRanger This book is published in DM's Guild, so I should have access to any famous names. No need to worry about copyright for now, I think. The book is also non-profit, if that matters

Comment: @Eddymage From the wiki, somewhere in 1489 DR. Should match the beginning of 5th edition

Comment: @NautArch Ideally, famous/powerful Storm Sorcerers. In the event there are none, famous/powerful characters who fight using the power of storms (thunder, lightning, rain)

Comment: @BlueMoon93 If you're publishing under the DM's Guild License, using FR content while selling it for a profit should be allowed. https://support.dmsguild.com/hc/en-us/articles/217520927-Ownership-and-License-OGL-Questions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**King Hekaton might fit your requirements**

Unless you need a character from one of the playable races.

King Hekaton, from Storm King's Thunder pg. 222, is the king of the storm giants, and therefore on top of the ordning. Since you are attacking a flying fortress of cloud giants, the cloud giants might have angered him in some way. I am not familiar with the cloud giants agenda in Hoard of the Dragon Queen.

> For as long as Hekaton had reigned, fear of the king’s wrath and respect for the ordning was enough to keep lesser giants from rising up against him.

King Hekaton also have access to a lightning attack and control over weather. And storm giants rely on Rocs to fly, which would help him access the flying fortress.

He should also be alive around 1489 DR.

Comment: This is great. And I won't spoil the adventure, but there is reason for the King to be angry at these giants. +1

Comment: This is actually amazing, in the official lore Hekaton gets kidnapped and killed by the Cult of the Dragon, the main antagonists of Hoard of the Dragon Queen. Wow!

Comment: If the official lore you are referencing is the Storm King's Thunder adventure, then King Hekaton is kidnapped (and is still alive when the adventurers find him) by the Kraken Society. But behind the conspiracy there is a dragon, Iymrith. And there is a lot of connections to build on around the rivalry between giants and dragons.